# FullCalendar - random busy block and detecting click on busy block

Tags: fullcalendar

I am working with fullcalendar here and have some problems with the appearance of it.

I want to have a working time, for example from 8:00 am to 5:00 pm and I know how to manage to gray out slots in non-working time with the `businessHours` option:

```
businessHours: {
  dow: [1,2,3,4,5],
  start: '08:00',
  end: '17:00'
}
```

But let's say, for example, I want to show only events and not all the working time, so at the beginning `businessHours` is set as:

```
businessHours: {
  dow: [1,2,3,4,5],
  start: '00:00',
  end: '00:00'
}
```

Now, when some things here are selected, besides events that are already on the calendar I am showing the full working time for the day.

But here's my problem:

I have some resources unavailable, let's say, from 8:30 to 9:00 and from 13:45 to 14:00, and from 15:00 to 16:00.

1) Is there a way to make those blocks unavailable for making events, so when click on the block is registered, a message pops up: "This slot (or something) is unavailable.

2) Is there a way to register click on non-working hours and slots (blocks), all of them, inside the calendar (from 8:30 to 9:00 and from 13:45 to 14:00, and from 15:00 to 16:00) and outside of it - from 00:00 to 8:00 and from 17:00 to 00:00?

Comment: 1) you could use background events to mark these blocks, and then detect people trying to create events in them, and disallow it if it's a background event: `eventOverlap: function(stillEvent, movingEvent) {
    return stillEvent.rendering != "background";
}` You could also put an alert in there as well to display your message, if you wanted.

Comment: 2) not directly no. You'd have to handle all clicks using `dayClick` I think, then manually look at the selected date/time to see where it lies in relation to your businessHours and unavailable background slots.